# What search algorithm is better to use in such a case?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I need to find the elements by "zone", here is an array:

```
0: Array[2]
 0: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 7
 1: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 12
1: Array[2]
 0: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 7
 1: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 12
2: Array[2]
 0: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 8
 1: Object
   busyLinesCount: 4
   zone: 13
```

I think that this is better to search just in a loop, but I am not really sure about that!

I really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to find objects with a single zone value, then you won't be able to do anything better than just a single loop, of course.

If you have multiple queries, then you can create an array of lists, where `table[zone_number]` is a list of objects having their zone equal to `zone_number`. Then, for every `zone_number` you can achieve `O(1)` complexity of finding the whole list. Or, if zones numbers are sparse and/or their values could be huge, you can make a map (dictionary) instead of arrays and achieve `O(log [number of distinct zones])` complexity with pretty much the same syntax.